# Setting up Input Masking with jQuery ruby gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jquery-inputmask

I have been trying to implement input masking on my site for the phone number field. For some (probably silly) reason I am having trouble getting my code to link with the jQuery plugin. I downloaded the Ruby gem and did all of the steps but my browser is saying that the variables are not defined. I suspect I did not set up the gem correctly.

[Github link](https://github.com/maurcarvalho/jquery_mask_rails#jquery-mask-for-rails)

[The main website for the functionality](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

I have installed the gem into my gemfile and run bundle

I have included the call into my application.js

Then tried to implement it in my code

I know it needs the file: `jquery.mask.min.js` but cannot link it with my project

If there is any easier way to implement this functionality in Ruby on Rails I'd love to use it!

PS: I am coming back to coding after a long break so I am having trouble doing simple things like this!

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label>Phone</label>

<%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'control phone_us', maxlength: 20 %>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
  })
</script>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: ".phone_us".mask is not a function

    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:19)
    at mightThrow (jquery3.self-e200ee796ef24add7054280d843a80de75392557bb4248241e870fac0914c0c1.js?body=1:3558)
    at process (jquery3.self-e200ee796ef24add7054280d843a80de75392557bb4248241e870fac0914c0c1.js?body=1:3626)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a `$` in front of `('.phone_us')`. Like:

```
$('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
```

Also, if you're using turbolinks, you'll likely need to listen for the `turbolinks:load` event, like:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

As stated in the docs under [5.2 Page Change Events](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events).

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed it :)